# Get the values of a hidden input a table Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Suppose I have a table like this:

```html
<table id="parameters" width="100%" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Identity</th>
      <th>Names</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Concept</th>
      <th>Select</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2016-08-10<input type="hidden" name="date[]" value="2016-08-10"></td>
      <td>12345678<input type="hidden" name="identity[]" value="12345678"></td>
      <td>Pepito Perez</td>
      <td>2.5<input type="hidden" name="value[]" value="2.5"></td>
      <td>daytime<input type="hidden" name="concept[]" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="12345678"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2016-08-10<input type="hidden" name="fecha[]" value="2016-08-10"></td>
      <td>24681012<input type="hidden" name="identity[]" value="24681012"></td>
      <td>Camilo Sanchez</td>
      <td>2.5<input type="hidden" name="value[]" value="2.5"></td>
      <td>daytime<input type="hidden" name="concept[]" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="24681012"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2016-08-10<input type="hidden" name="fecha[]" value="2016-08-10"></td>
      <td>369121518<input type="hidden" name="identity[]" value="369121518"></td>
      <td>Pepito Perez</td>
      <td>2.5<input type="hidden" name="value[]" value="2.5"></td>
      <td>daytime<input type="hidden" name="concept[]" value="1"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="369121518"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

This table is generated according to a query, the id of the checkbox is the identity value of each employee .

I want to get the value of the hidden input only from the checkbox selected in an array and then send that data by ajax and then save them in the database:

```
//Here, when clicking the button confirm searches the table that are marked
confirm.on('click', function(){
//Save in result inputs with marked checkbox
      $("#parameters tbody tr td input[name=check]:checked").each(function(){
        var result = [];
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(){
          result.push($(this).serializeArray());
        });

//sending the object by ajax
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url:  getBaseUri()+'/payroll/createAll/',
          data: {datas: result},
          cache: false,
          success: function (response) {
            var table = tableConfirm;
            var url = table.data('source');
            clearFom();
            table.dataTable().fnReloadAjax(url);
          },
          error: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
          }
        });
      });
```

I wonder what I'm doing wrong and if there is a better way to send the data by ajax to store them in the database because I receive the object like this:

```
$datas = 
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => date
                        [value] => 2016-08-10
                    )

            )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => identity
                [value] => 11434058
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => company
                [value] => 1
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => cc
                [value] => 2
            )

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => value
                [value] => 6
            )

    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => qov
                [value] => 1
            )

    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => concept
                [value] => 3
            )

    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => land
                [value] => 1
            )

    )
)
```

And I need to save this array in the database, but I can´t do it.

Comment: instead of this           result.push($(this).serializeArray());
try this           result.push($(this).val());

Comment: Yes it runs thank You!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$("#parameters tbody tr td input[name=check]:checked").each(function(){
        var result = [];
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(){
          result.push($(this).val());
        });
```

Yes I changed `.serializeArrya()` by `.val()` and it runs.